# React Native Textinput wont call onchange on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, textinput

I have a problem with my react-native app. I have simple input for the note, it works as expected on Android, but on iOS onChange/onChangeText method is never called. It is weird because i see correct value in input, but if I console.log in onChange method, its never called. What am I missing here?

```
const [noteEdit, _setNoteEdit] = useState(note)
const noteRef = React.useRef(noteEdit);

const setNoteEdit = event => {
        const note= event.nativeEvent.text;
        _setNoteEdit(note);
        noteRef.current = note;
    }

<TextInput multiline={true} 
                value={noteEdit} onChange={setNoteEdit} autoCorrect={false} />
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to try this below hope it's working

```
 const [noteEdit, _setNoteEdit] = useState('')

<TextInput multiline={true} 
            value={noteEdit} onChangeText={(text)=>_setNoteEdit(text)} autoCorrect={false} />
```

Comment: It is not working, same issue

Comment: can you use "onChangeText" instead of "onChange"